# Unknown property 'ApexPages.StandardSetController

Tags: visualforce, pagination

I've a requirement where on VF page there would be a button on click of which data would be retrieved from an end point which is to be then shown on the same page. For pagination purpose I decided to get the response from the service and store it as records on a custom object.

While trying to save I'm getting this error -

> Error: Unknown property 'ApexPages.StandardSetController.fname'

Following is the apex class and VF page:

```
global class TestDataContactsController{

    public List<conWrapper> conWrappers {get; set;}
    List<conWrapper> conWrapperLstFrmSrvc = new List<conWrapper>();

    // instantiate the StandardSetController from a query locator
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController con {
        get {
            if(con == null) {
                con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id, ConFirstName__c,ConLastName__c,UserName__c FROM ConWrapper__c]));
                // sets the number of records in each page set
                con.setPageSize(5);
            }
            return con;
        }
        set;
    }

    public boolean tableVisiblity {get; set;}
    public boolean isUsernameVisible {get; set;}

    public TestDataContactsController() {
        tableVisiblity = false;
        Id profileId=userinfo.getProfileId();
        String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:profileId].Name;
        if(profileName == 'Custom: System Admin')
            isUsernameVisible = true;
        else
            isUsernameVisible = false;
    }

       public  void getConData() {

        //Define http Request 
        //append your Query to the base url
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http:sampleEndpoint/?rows=500&fname= 
          {firstName}&lname={lastName}&uname={username}&delay=20');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setTimeout(120000);

        //Get SessionId
        string autho = 'Bearer '+userInfo.getSessionId();
        req.setHeader('Authorization', autho);

        //Get Response
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPresponse res= http.send(req);
        string response = res.getBody();

        //Deserialize obtained json response
        conWrapperLstFrmSrvc  = (List<conWrapper>)JSON.deserialize(response, List<conWrapper>.class);

        List<ConWrapper__c> conWrapList = new List<ConWrapper__c>();
        for(conWrapper conRec : conWrapperLstFrmSrvc){
            ConWrapper__c conWrapper = new ConWrapper__c();
            conWrapper.ConFirstName__c = conRec.fname;
            conWrapper.ConLastName__c = conRec.lname;
            conWrapper.UserName__c= conRec.uname;
            conWrapList.add(conWrapper);
        }
        if(!conWrapList.isEmpty()){
            insert conWrapList;
        }

        tableVisiblity = true;   
    }

    public List<conWrapper> getConWrapperList(){
        conWrappers = new List<conWrapper>();
        for (ConWrapper__c cWrp: (List<ConWrapper__c>)con.getRecords())
            conWrappers.add(new conWrapper(cWrp));

        return conWrappers;
    }

    public PageReference saveData(){
        List<Contact> contList = new List<Contact>();
        if(conWrappers <> null && conWrappers.size() > 0){
            for(conWrapper conRec : conWrappers){
                Contact c = new Contact();
                c.FirstName = conRec.fname;
                c.LastName = conRec.lname;
                contList.add(c);
            }
            System.debug('***:'+contList);
            if(contList <> null && contList.size() > 0)
                Database.Insert(contList, FALSE);
        }
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/TestDataContacts');
        return pageRef;
    }

    // returns the first page of records
    public void first() {
        con.first();
    }

    // returns the last page of records
    public void last() {
        con.last();
    }

    // returns the previous page of records
    public void previous() {
        con.previous();
    }

    // returns the next page of records
    public void next() {
        con.next();
    }

    public PageReference cancel(){
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/003?fcf=00B7F000003zadT');
            return pageRef;
    }

    public class conWrapper{
        public String fname{get; set;}
        public String lname{get; set;}
        public String uname{get; set;}

        public conWrapper(ConWrapper__c cWrp){
            this.fname = cWrp.ConFirstName__c;
            this.lname = cWrp.ConLastName__c;
            this.uname = cWrp.UserName__c;
        }
    }

    }


    <apex:page controller="TestDataContactsController" showHeader="true" sidebar="false" lightningStyleSheets="true">
    <div style="width:100%; text-align: center">
    <script>
          function showAlert() {
               alert('Your data has been saved !');
               window.location.reload();
           }
    </script>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:slds />
            <apex:pageBlock id="details" title="Test Data - Contacts">
                <apex:outputPanel id="rootContainer">
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!tableVisiblity}">
                        <apex:outputPanel ></apex:outputPanel>

                        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ConWrapperList}" var="c">
                            <apex:column value="{!c.fname}" headerValue="First Name"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!c.lname}" headerValue="Last Name"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!c.uname}" headerValue="User Name" rendered="{!isUsernameVisible}"/>
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>

                    </apex:outputPanel><!--End Root Container--> 
                </apex:outputPanel>

                <apex:outputPanel id="rootContainer1">
                    <center>  
                        <apex:actionStatus id="loading" layout="block">
                            <apex:facet name="start">
                                <div id="assign-action-spinner-main">
                                    <div id="assign-action-spinner-content">
                                        <img src="/img/analytics/reportbuilder/icons/spinner32.gif" alt="Processing..." title="Processing..." />
                                        <p>Processing...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </apex:facet>
                        </apex:actionStatus>
                    </center>
                </apex:outputPanel><!--End Root Container--> 

                <apex:pageblockButtons location="top" style="float:right;">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!getConData}" value="Retrieve" status="loading" reRender="details" rendered="{!!tableVisiblity}"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!saveData}" value="Save" rendered="{!tableVisiblity}" oncomplete="showAlert();"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
                </apex:pageblockButtons>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:panelGrid columns="4">
                <apex:commandLink action="{!first}">First</apex:commandlink>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" rendered="{!hasPrevious}">Previous</apex:commandlink>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" rendered="{!hasNext}">Next</apex:commandlink>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!last}">Last</apex:commandlink>
            </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:form>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Can someone help me with the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iteration variable in your pageBlockTable

```
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ConWrapperList}" var="con">
```

has a namespace collision with your property

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController con {
```

Visualforce is resolving these references to the latter, which doesn't have an `fname` property.

Change the name of your iteration variable and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks David! An additional ask here - do you find any issue as to how I've implemented pagination in this case like using an additional custom object to store the records coming from webservice?

Comment: It seems heavy. I'm not sure if there is a purpose to persisting those records to the database besides using the Standard Set Controller. If not, I would just do it in pure Apex so you don't need an extra sObject.

Comment: As far I know using pure Apex if I've to do it I need to do a SOQL and then break the resulting records for pagination that's why I used an additional object..could you please just give me some hint as to how we can avoid this just by using Apex and not an additional object?

Comment: I was suggesting that you not use a Standard Set Controller, but simply store the wrapper objects in your view state and paginate them manually in your controller. I don't have any idea of how big your data set is, though, so that may not be a viable solution. If your solution works for you, go for it!